# Apache doesn't pass through dot in rewrite rule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpg|png|js|css)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

If the URL is:

`http://localhost/blah...../`

Apache doesn't pass through the dots in the `url` query string, you just see it as `blah/`

What would be the reason behind this and how can I solve it?

Comment: Are you sure? I tested it and it does show `$_GET["url"]='blah...../'`

Comment: yeh 100% must be the environment setup... what version apache did you test on? it must be a setting or something :-S

Comment: I am using `Apache/2.2.22`

Comment: Just to let you know I have been trying to reproduce your problem but for me its always reporting correct query string. Can you try adding `R` flag and see if it changes the behavior in the redirected URI.

Comment: What OS or filesystem are each of you using? Might not be Apache that is trimming the periods away.

Comment: I am on Mac OSX 10.6.8

Comment: I'm using XP and adding the `R` flag does the redirect but the . is still missing from the param string